# How to get the options for a custom field in Jira?

Tags: python, jira

In the Jira issue I'm looking at, there are fields with a drop down list for valid values. I would like to access that drop down list using python. When looking at the returned fields for the issue, the object has a value `customfield_14651` which is an object with `value` and `id`. [Jira documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jira/stable/jira.pdf) shows there is a `custom_field_option()` method which should return the fields? I call the method like below:

```
self.jira = JIRA('https://jira.companyname.com',basic_auth (login['username'], login['password']) )
print self.jira.custom_field_option('14651')
```

and receive back the following error:
`response text = {"errorMessages":["A custom field option with id '14651' does not exist"],"errors":{}}`

Comment: I have tried working with python api and had alot of problems so I used regular API https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/. I found it easier to massage the data this way.

Comment: IMHO, the id should be something like `customfield_12345` instead of `14561`. Kindly check once again!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer `response text = {"errorMessages":["A custom field option with id 'customfield_14651' does not exist"]`

Comment: Just by the way. Regardless to library you use there only one method in raw Jira REST API returns data about custom field options - "createmeta". Its have a bug about disabled custom field values have described in https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-61594. If be briefly when you disable field then you still see it in REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jira has the `.fields()` function which returns a list of all fields that are visible to the account you are using.

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'password'), options = {'server': 'url'})

# Fetch all fields
allfields = jira.fields()

# Make a map from field name -> field id
name_map = {field['name']:field['id'] for field in allfields}
```

`name_map` is now a dict in the format of `{"field name":"customfield_xxxx", ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way to do this in the API is:

```
from jira import JIRA
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('username', 'password'), options = {'server': 'url'})

# get an example issue that has the field you're interested in 
issue = jira("PRJ-1")
meta = jira.editmeta(issue)

# inspect the meta to get the field you want to look at
allowed_values = [v['value'] for v in meta['fields']['customfield_99999']['allowedValues']]
```